# Powershell: How to use Format-Table with XML data

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

```
<tickets type="array">
    <ticket>
        <assigned-user-id type="integer">123</assigned-user-id>
        <closed type="boolean">true</closed>
        <creator-id type="integer">177522</creator-id>
        <number type="integer">306</number>
        <state>resolved</state>
        <tag nil="true"/>
        <title>
        title text 1
        </title>
        <updated-at type="datetime">2012-03-14T13:13:11+11:00</updated-at>
        <user-id type="integer">96438</user-id>
        <version type="integer">3</version>
        <user-name>Username</user-name>
    </ticket>
</tickets>
```

I am a Powershell newbie and find a question on xml and format-table. Given above xml file. If I run below script to display tickets in a table, the value of "number", "closed" could not be shown

```
$t = [xml](new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring($xmlfilepath)
$t.tickets.ticket | Format-Table -Property title, state, user-name, url, number, closed
```

Return:

```
title            state       user-name       number       closed                                      
-----            -----       ---------       ------       ------                                
title text 1     resolved    Username        number       closed   
title text 2     resolved    Username        number       closed
```

Is it the only way I have to use `foreach` and `selectSingleNode("ticket").get_InnerXml()` to get all the values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you notice those nodes have attributes so you will need to get to the data of the node. try the following:

```
$t.tickets.ticket | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property title, state, user-name, url,
@{Label="number"; Expression={$_.number."#text"}},
@{Label="closed"; Expression={$_.closed."#text"}}
```