# Use Format-Table to format XML node with attribute

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

[Powershell: How to use Format-Table with XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797693/powershell-how-to-use-format-table-with-xml-data) details how do handle XML elements with attributes.  My situation is a variation of this.

In most cases, no attribute is present:

```
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Title>Vivamus fermentum semper porta</d:Title>
```

which can be handled with this code:

```
...
$properties = $xml.feed.entry.content.properties
$properties | Format-Table -Property @{Label="Title"; Expression={$_.Title}}
...
```

or even:

```
$properties | Format-Table -Property Title
```

In a few cases, however, the `xml:space` attribute is present:

```
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Title xml:space="preserve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </d:Title>
```

which requires this code:

```
...
$properties = $xml.feed.entry.content.properties
$properties | Format-Table -Property @{Label="Title"; Expression={$_.Title."#text"}}
...
```

Is there a DRYer way to handle this situation?

Comment: I think I have an idea but can you include a sample that has both variances you are referring to for testing. Since your second snippet looks _very_ similar to the first.

Answer (score 0):

I initially was trying to come up with something more complicated but if this suits your needs I don't need to pull my hair out. I made a function that will check the object passed. If that object contains "`#text`" property then we return it. Else just return the object passed.

```powershell
function Get-XMLElementStringData{
    param(
        # In testing could be a string or System.Xml.XmlElement so I do not type this
        $Element
    )

    # Check for the existence of the property. There are other methods but the result is the same. 
    # If($Element."#text"){$Element."#text"} would also work.
    If($Element.PsObject.Properties.Name -contains "#text"){
        $Element."#text"
    } Else {
        $Element
    }
}
```

With that I was able to change your output code just like this:

```powershell
$properties | Format-Table @{Label="Title"; Expression={Get-XMLElementStringData $_.Title}}
```

If you are looking for a *DRYer* way then maybe we can work on another approach.