# Powershell formatting imported XML as a datatable

Tags: xml, powershell, datatable

I am using Powershell to import an XML file and I would like to format the data as a datatable.

Using the question below I can view the data as a table in the powershell console.

[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797693/powershell-how-to-use-format-table-with-xml-data)

The powershell I produced from this question is shown below.

```
$peakPrices = $dt.heml.Transactions.Record | format-table -AutoSize -Property @{Label="Period";Expression={$_.column[0]."#text"}},
@{label="PeaksBid";Expression={$_.column[9]."#text"}}, @{label="PeaksOffer";Expression={$_.Column[11]."#text"}}, @{label="ReportDate";Expression={$todaysDate}}
```

This produces a nice view of the data in the form of a table but I dont seem to be able to do what I want with it i.e. loop through each row and do stuff.

The resultant table from the code above looks similar to this.

[image: Picture of table]

I would like to change this data to a datatable as I am competent at manipulating these.  Is this something I can do?

Comment: Use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`

Comment: spot on thank you, how I do mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format-Table` will return pre-formatted data for displaying in the host application. If you want to select calculated properties for further processing use `Select-Object` instead:

```
... | Select-Object -Property @{Label="Period";Expression={$_.column[0]."#text"}},@{label="PeaksBid";Expression={$_.column[9]."#text"}}, @{label="PeaksOffer";Expression={$_.Column[11]."#text"}}, @{label="ReportDate";Expression={$todaysDate}}
```